# What's the best route to all targets on R&D side mission?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain, metal-gear-solid

Someome know a good route to get all the target's on the R&D Target Practice side mission? I'm trying to minimize the record on the mission

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the below YouTube video, pausing it as I went along and doing small chunks at a time.

As the timer obviously doesn't increase when the game is paused, it is a good method for getting a good time.